# How to use inline utilizing username and password in a stored procedure for MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to create an import using infile to create a stored procedure.
How can I add username and password?  I can't find documentation.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: Import... to create a stored Proceedure? Sorry but I dont think that makes any sence

Comment: _How can I add username and password_? Add them to what from what? Again struggling a little to make sence of what you have said

Comment: Sorry I need to import a CSV file.  I need to set it to run automatically via job calling a  Stored procedure.  I have to use username and password.  I can only find the information for the infile like the one above that does not have the u/p.  So the sorry infile.

Comment: I think i need to be even more specific.  The file itself is not password protected.  The mysql needs the username and password to gain access to import the data into the table that is already created on the server.

Comment: *The mysql needs the username and password to gain access to import the data into the table that is already created on the server.* Specify CREATOR clause in CREATE PROCEDURE and use SECURITY CREATOR option.

Comment: Do you know a website with an example?